# Run multiple activity instances in Android from the single same class and move to the first instance on a button click

Tags: android

I have an activity A ,am calling the same activity again and again like A calls another A in turn it calls another A and so on.I am not finishing any of these activities.My problem is when I click a button in any of the inner A ,I want to go the A that was first created and need to remove all other A's on the top of it.How to do this?

Intent itent = new Intent(A.this,A.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Are you talking about recursion? If so, then you must know that to escape such a process you will need some sort of base case

Answer (score 0):

if you are using intents use like this

```
Intent b = new Intent(Xyz.this, 
                Abc.class);


         b.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

         startActivity(b);
```